# Pandas groupby: fill missing values from other group members

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan, pandas-groupby

I think this is best shown with an example. What I'm trying to do is find the non-null number from a group and propagate it to the rest of the group.

```
In [52]: df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({1:{'i_id': 2, 'i_num':1}, 2: {'i_id': 2, 'i_num': np.nan}, 3: {'i_id': 2, 'i_num': np.nan}, 4: {'i_id': 3, 'i_num': np.nan}, 5: {'i_id': 3, 'i_num': 5}}, orient='index')

In [53]: df
Out[53]:
   i_num  i_id
1      1     2
2    NaN     2
3    NaN     2
4    NaN     3
5      5     3
```

The DataFrame would look something like this. What I want is to take all the i_id == 2 and make their i_num == 1, and all the i_id == 3, and make their i_num == 5 (so both matching their non-null group neighbors).

So the end result would be this:

```
   i_num  i_id
1      1     2
2      1     2
3      1     2
4      5     3
5      5     3
```

Comment: What if there is more than one unique `i_num` for a given `i_id`?  How do you choose which value to then fill?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`first` finds the first non-null value in a group. You can fill in the other values in each group like this:

```
df['i_num'] = df.groupby('i_id')['i_num'].transform('first')
```

This produces the column as required:

```
   i_num  i_id
1      1     2
2      1     2
3      1     2
4      5     3
5      5     3
```

Bear in mind that this will replace all values in the group with the first value, not just `NaN` values (this seems to be what you're looking for here though).

Alternatively - and to respect any other non-null values in the group - you can use `fillna` in the following way:

```
# make a column of first values for each group
x = df['i_id'].map(df.groupby('i_id')['i_num'].first())
# fill only NaN values using new column x
df['i_num'] = df['i_num'].fillna(x)
```