# How to merge rows with ID column in common in Python to produce a single row

Tags: python, merge, duplicates, aggregate

I have 95% completed my project but I am having issues with duplicates where I do not what there to be duplicates. I would like them merged into one row.

**Final Output in Excel looks like: **

| P ID | T ID | C ID | Q1 | Q2 | Q3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 318 | 495 | 00036282 | NO |  |  |
| 318 | 495 | 00036282 |  | Yes | All cost covered |
| 319 | 496 | 00036283 | Yes |  | No additional costs |
| 319 | 496 | 00036283 |  | Yes |  |

This output currently has 3130 rows

**What I want it to look like in Excel: **

| P ID | T ID | C ID | Q1 | Q2 | Q3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 318 | 495 | 00036282 | NO | Yes | All cost covered |
| 319 | 496 | 00036283 | Yes | Yes | No additional costs |

My ideal output has about 900 rows and I want all columns in the final output

So far I have attempted:

1. Dropping duplicates using the ‘drop_duplicates()’ function.
2. Grouping by Property ID and aggregating the rows.
3. Concatenating rows with similar Property IDs while preserving unique values
4. Manually inspecting the data set for any inconsistencies or patterns ( while I can locate them, this cannot sufficiently solve the problem, because it requires the Excel version as a validation which is counterproductive to the point of the automation)

```
# Group by P Id and aggregate using sum for numeric columns
df_FinalOutput_summed = df_FinalOutput.groupby('P Id').sum().reset_index()
df_FinalOutput_summed
```

```
df_FinalOutput = df_FinalOutput.groupby('P Id').agg({
       'T Id': 'last',
       'C ID': 'last',
         'Q1': 'last' 
         'Q2': 'last'
         'Q3': 'last'
}).reset_index()

# Reset index after grouping
df_FinalOutput.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

# Display the final output DataFrame
df_FinalOutput
```

This code chunk is close to what I need but I don't want to just pick the last row, I want to merge the rows so I get one column with all the details in it.

Answer (score 0):

With the given test data either `bfill`+`head` or `ffill`+`tail` seems to do the job.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "P ID": [318, 318, 319, 319],
        "T ID": [495, 495, 496, 496],
        "C ID": ["00036282", "00036282", "00036283", "00036283"],
        "Q1": ["NO", None, "Yes", None],
        "Q2": [None, "Yes", None, "Yes"],
        "Q3": [None, "All cost covered", "No additional costs", None],
    }
)

df.groupby("P ID").apply(lambda x: x.bfill().head(1)).reset_index(drop=True)
```

[Another solution could be to use `fillna` and `first`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34186946/pandas-groupby-fill-missing-values-from-other-group-members) This question could also be a duplicate of the one in the link.